# NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID while recording from playwright

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, uiautomation, playwright

While I'm trying to record the web based application using Playwright tool and after launching the application getting as NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID [image].

After recording and in the playwright tool the application url code is not getting recorded.[image]

getting error as [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you trust the domain, or are using your own self-signed certificate, this error can be avoided by adding `ignoreHTTPSError: true` when creating the context:

```
... = browser.newContext({ ignoreHTTPSErrors: true });
```

or in Python

```py
... = browser.new_context(ignore_https_errors=True)
```

or in C#

```cs
... = browser.NewContextAsync(new BrowserNewContextOptions { IgnoreHTTPSErrors = true });
```

Or when starting `codegen`:

```bash
playwright codegen https://localhost/ --ignore-https-errors
```